# How to enable a button using angulars ngForm when an item is removed from an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have a form using AngularJS *ngForm* directive. This form shows a list of items in an array, and clicking on any item removes it from the array.  The button is disabled by default and should be enabled if an item is removed from an array.

Is there a way to have ngForm track changes to an array and set the `$pristine` state so that the button will toggle between *disabled* and *enabled*?

Here is a plnkr that I created demonstrating my use of ngForm and a list. Clicking on an item in the list removes the item from the list, but does not enable the button. https://plnkr.co/edit/am8jIazJmKtabx37Ev8C

Here is my example code.

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', [function() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.data = [1, 2, 3];

  vm.removeItem = function(i) {
    var index = vm.data.indexOf(i);
    vm.data.splice(index, 1);
  }

}]);
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController as vm">
    <div ng-form="form">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="i in vm.data" ng-click="vm.removeItem(i)">
          Click to remove item - {{i}}
        </li>
      </ul>

      <button type="button" ng-disabled="form.$pristine">
        submit
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you don't want to use `$scope`. First you must declare your form on the `vm` variable like the code below, then your controller will be able to see your form.

```
<form ng-form="vm.form">
...
</form>
```

So then, inside the controller you can force a `$dirty` instead of a `$pristine`. The `$priestine` state means that the form is untouched, in this case you want to set te oposite of untouched that is `$dirty` according to [Angularjs docs for `form.FormController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController).

```
...
vm.form.$setDirty();
...
```

Full code:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', [function() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.data = [1, 2, 3];

  vm.removeItem = function(i) {
    var index = vm.data.indexOf(i);
    vm.data.splice(index, 1);
    vm.form.$setDirty();
  }

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController as vm">
    <div ng-form="vm.form">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="i in vm.data" ng-click="vm.removeItem(i)">
          Click to remove item - {{i}}
        </li>
      </ul>

      <button type="button" ng-disabled="vm.form.$pristine">
        submit
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I had seen examples of ngForm disabling a button when form input elements were changed, but since this is not a traditional form input element I was not sure how to approach it.  Thank you!

Comment: @Mdd Well, it can be used to do such things, as you can see in my answer, it's not just for traditional form elements, it also can be used for complex and modern form components. Anyways, the main goal is to give a proper answer for the problem you described. Now people can use this ideia in a similar context.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it in code: `$scope.form.$setPristine();`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

**EDIT**
But I'd use a separate variable:

```
<button type="button" ng-disabled="!vm.enableButton">
      submit
</button>
```

and

```
app.controller('MyController', [function() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.enableButton = false;

  vm.data = [1, 2, 3];

  vm.removeItem = function(i) {
    var index = vm.data.indexOf(i);
    vm.data.splice(index, 1);

    vm.enableButton = true;
  }

}]);
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/S8QgytDskCBKadHasjF1?p=preview

Comment: Would this mean having to include `$scope` as a dependency even though `controller as` syntax is used?

Comment: You won't need `$scope`. I didn't note the ControllerAs syntax

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that I could set the `ng-form` value to `vm` in this case. I had not seen the page on formController when I initially looked up ngForm.

Answer (score 0):

`$pristine` is about user interaction with form controls. Your UI not offering user traditional interactions but instead modify bound data. That's why `$pristine` is not changes in such interactions. So you can either call `$scope.form.$setDirty()` in your method, or set some flag and use it for ng-disabled, or use your array length check instead of that flag:

```
ng-disabled="vm.data.length == 3"
```

Comment: Thank you! the `$scope.form.$setDirty()` did the trick.  I thought it might be something to do with the displayed list not being a traditional form-input element, but I was not sure how angulars ngForm really handles things. Thanks!

Comment: You welcome! Actually it's really simple, take a look: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController